# PHP Trader Function: trader_sma, when it asks for time period, what type of period is it asking? Days, Seconds, etc?

Tags: php, ta-lib

PHP Trader Function: trader_sma, when it asks for time period, what type of period is it asking ? Days, Seconds, etc?

```
Regarding: array trader_sma ( array $real [, integer $timePeriod ] )
```

Any insight regarding this function would be very appreciated. The trader functions are highly undocumented. If you know of any documentation, let me know about it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not asking for a *type* of period; it's asking how many periods to use in calculating the simple moving average.

Comment: Yes, I understood that it wasn't asking for you to define the type (i.e.; day/hour/second), I just wasn't sure what the time period represented....but basically from what you're saying, a time period of 2==2 trading days? Sorry, just want to be sure.

Comment: It's whatever you pass in the array, as I understand it. If you pass it daily data, you get a daily MA. Pass it hourly data, you get an hourly MA, etc.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you. I just don't know why they included the time period param...but you answered my question, I appreciate your time.

Comment: For anybody that stumbles upon this question: Time Period represents days of trading (Valid range from 2 to 100000).